# Get to Post function

Tags: html, post, get

I got an URL in a  html tag, so in a GET format :

```
http://toto.fr/grc/start.swe?SWECmd=ExecuteLogin&SWEAC=SWECmd=InvokeMethod&SWEMethod=GotoView&SWEService=GRC+Debranchement+Generique&BusObject=Contact&BusComp=Contact&ViewName=GRC+Contact+Synthetic+View&SWEUserName=titi&SWEPassword=toto&ValeurChamp=35925436&Champ=Person UId
```

I want to call it in POST. Is there a way to do this easily ?

Comment: you can use Fiddler to make Post or some similar tools

Comment: In a browser on a website? The question isn't clear at all

Comment: It's in a website, using a <A> html tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an HTML form with all the URL parameters as hidden variables.

e.g.

```
<form action="http://toto.fr/grc/start.swe" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="SWECmd" value="ExecuteLogin" />
  <!--- repeat for all other parameters --->
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't clear at all... It's an URL in a <A> tag, not in a <FORM> tag. Use a FORM is the only way ?

Comment: Yes, using a form is the only way to create a POST request.  The <A> tag will always produce a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `<form method="GET">` to `<form method="POST">`
if this doesn't work, could you post your code?

Comment: why the -1? I can't understand, we are just trying to help.

Comment: I didnt downvote, however the OP has stated its an anchor tag, not a form

Answer (score 0):

I've just been thinking about this again and if you really do need to have a link submit a POST request then it may be possible by giving the form an id attribute, create your link with an id attribute and then you can add a click event handler which will submit the form in Javascript.

See the mock-up code below (syntax may not be perfect!)...

HTML.

```
<form id="loginForm" action="http://toto.fr/grc/start.swe" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="SWECmd" value="ExecuteLogin" />
  <!--- repeat for all other parameters --->
</form>

<a id="LoginLink" href="#">Login</a>
```

Javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var loginForm = document.getElementById('loginForm');
  var loginLink = document.getElementById('loginLink');

  loginLink.addEventListener('click', login);

  var login = function() {
    loginForm.submit();
  }
</script>
```